# Does it make sense to use big-O to describe the best case for a function?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, theory, discrete-mathematics

I have an extremely pedantic question on big-O notation that I would like some opinions on. One of my uni subjects states “Best O(1) if their first element is the same” for a question on checking if two lists have a common element.

My qualm with this is that it does not describe the function on the entire domain of large inputs, rather the restricted domain of large inputs that have two lists with the same first element. Does it make sense to describe a function by only talking about a subset of that function’s domain? Of course, when restricted to that domain, the time complexity is omega(1), O(1) and therefore theta(1), but this isn’t describing the original function. From my understanding it would be more correct to say the entire function is bounded by omega(1). (and O(m*n) where m, n are the sizes of the two input lists).

What do all of you think?

Comment: Please consider posting and following up on the companion forum that is dedicated to comp sci topics https://cs.stackexchange.com/ - I believe SO is not intended to resolve general purpose comp sci knowledge rather than specific engineering problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, big-O notation is a way of talking about how some quantity scales. In CS we so often see it used for talking about algorithm runtimes that we forget that all the following are perfectly legitimate use cases for it:

- The area of a circle of radius r is O(r<sup>2</sup>).
- The volume of a sphere of radius r is O(r<sup>3</sup>).
- The expected number of 2’s showing after rolling n dice is O(n).
- The minimum number of 2’s showing after rolling n dice is O(1).
- The number of strings made of n pairs of balanced parentheses is O(4<sup>n</sup>).

With that in mind, it’s perfectly reasonable to use big-O notation to talk about how the behavior of an algorithm in a specific family of cases will scale. For example, we could say the following:

- The time required to sort a sequence of n already-sorted elements with insertion sort is O(n). (There are other, non-sorted sequences where it takes longer.)
- The time required to run a breadth-first search of a tree with n nodes is O(n). (In a general graph, this could be larger if the number of edges were larger.)
- The time required to insert n items in sorted order into an initially empty binary heap is On). (This can be Θ(n log n) for a sequence of elements that is reverse-sorted.)

In short, it’s perfectly fine to use asymptotic notation to talk about restricted subcases of an algorithm. More generally, it’s fine to use asymptotic notation to describe how things grow as long as you’re precise about what you’re quantifying. See @Patrick87’s answer for more about whether to use O, Θ, Ω, etc. when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly correct to discuss cases (as you correctly point out, a case is a subset of the function's domain) and bounds on the runtime of algorithms in those cases (Omega, Oh or Theta). Whether or not it's useful is a harder question and one that is very situation-dependent. I'd generally think that Omega-bounds on the best case, Oh-bounds on the worst case and Theta bounds (on the "universal" case of all inputs, when such a bound exists) are the most "useful". But calling the subset of inputs where the first elements of each collection are the same, the "best case", seems like reasonable usage. The "best case" for bubble sort is the subset of inputs which are pre-sorted arrays, and is bound by O(n), better than unmodified merge sort's best-case bound.